# ZEND ACL roles - how to access them in helperss

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl

I have application\plugins\Acl.php with:

```
class Application_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
    $acl = new Zend_Acl();
```

and I add roles there. I also have heleper HasAccess.php:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_HasAccess extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    public function hasAccess($role, $action, $controller) {
    if (!$this->_acl) {
        $acl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getPlugin('Application_Plugin_Acl');
    }
    return $acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action);
```

and I cannot access roles from view files:

```
$this->hasAccess('user', 'partner', 'news')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in application\plugins\Acl.php  you have to attach that ACL instance to your views

```
class Application_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
    $acl = new Zend_Acl();

    // Set ACL to view files
    $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
    $view   = $layout->getView();
    $view->acl = $acl;
}
```

Than, you can use ACL in view files:

```
$this->acl->hasAccess(...);
```

if you want to use ACL in View Helpers, use:

```
$this->view->acl->hasAccess(...);
```

Comment: I tend to avoid assigning application wide variables or objects to the view as they may be automatically outputted if you serve json.

I think it's better to put the ACL in Zend_Registry (ZF1) and access it in the helper.

Comment: For my apps the best practise is to put ACL in DB, so I can manipulate with it (add role and resource, change permission...)